# Подсчёт количества вхождений подстроки в строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь реализовать программу подсчёта количества вхождений подстроки в строку на python. Не знаю почему в результате число вхождений равняется None.

```
s, t = input(), input()
count = 0
def define_number_of_includes(main, secondary):
   global count
   if main.find(secondary) != -1:
      if main.startswith(secondary):
         count = count + 1
      main = main[1:]
      print(count)
      print(main)
      define_number_of_includes(main, secondary)
   if main.find(secondary) == -1:
      return count
print(define_number_of_includes(s, t))
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что у Вас нет return в первом if, а соответственно, если подстрока есть в строке, то вывода не будет.

Comment: Строка 11: результат `define_number_of_includes(main, secondary)` нужно возвращать. Добавьте на этой строке `return`

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм у вас не совсем верный, плюс не сильно оптимизированный. Даже если вы добавите `return define_number_of_includes(main, secondary)` то ничего не поменяется

```
main = 'hello world, this is subtext of my big text that contains several subtext words in this text which used for subtextsubtext subtext counter subtext'
sub = 'subtext'

count = 0

def define_number_of_includes(mainText, subtext):
    global count
    found_subtext_idx = mainText.find(subtext) # ищем, есть ли в строке данный подтекст
    if found_subtext_idx != -1:
        count += 1 # если есть, добавляем +1
        # Берем и отрезаем уже найденный кусок текста
        subtext_len = len(subtext) 
        next_start_idx = found_subtext_idx + subtext_len
        next_part = mainText[next_start_idx:]
        print(next_part)
        return define_number_of_includes(next_part, subtext)
    else:
        return count

print(define_number_of_includes(main, sub))
```